# Google Compute Engine not following project instance defaults

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've created a new project in Google Cloud and specified the default instance type to be f1-micro. When I deploy my docker container, the net result is three instances.

1. A user-managed instance with my project name which is an f1-micro
2. Two google-managed instances named gae-default-xxx-yyy which have a machine type of "g1-small"

My billing statement reflects this as well. There is a line item for "Compute Engine Small instance..." and a line item for "Compute Engine Micro instance..."

I don't see a way to manage this default using `gcloud compute`. Why does my project behave this way and how can I limit the machine types to something more specific?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this yet? I have two questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530367/please-help-me-deploying-my-gwt-application-to-google-app-engine) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530442/why-are-instances-permanently-created-and-deleted-in-my-projects) which you might be able to answer.

Comment: Hi @Greg, can you provide us the way that you've used to create your containers? Also if you want, please put related configurations file, like google-container-manifest.