# Why are instances permanently created and deleted in my project(s)?

Tags: google-compute-engine

For some reason I see under "Operations" in my "Compute Engine" the following:

[image]

I would like to know/understand why this is happening. What is this *gae-default-** VM (assuming these are actually VMs)? What are they doing actually?

---

If you know a lot of stuff about GAE and the Compute Engine please consider taking a look at this question ["*Deploying a GWT application to Google Compute Engine - What is happening here?*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530367/please-help-me-deploying-my-gwt-application-to-google-app-engine) as well.

---

The CPU is getting utilized as well even though there can't be anything that runs:

[image]

If I manually delete those VMs they simply re-appear.

Comment: Is this still happening? Are you sure there is no-one else who is creating and deleting those instances. Seems like a scripted task.

Comment: @VikramTiwari I am the only one using this project and I am currently trying to deploy a GWT application (see the other question). Yes, this is still happening. I am adding a screenshot where you can see how the CPU is getting utilized for nothing ..

Answer (score 1):

GAE stands for [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/). Looks like you have some App Engine jobs configured. If you use the [flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) version then it would manage GCE instances on your behalf. I would imagine you should be able to find the running jobs in the web console.

Comment: Where would I find those jobs? I stopped and deleted those instances again and again but they reappear without me doing anything ..

Comment: I am not an app engine expert, but there is a whole section for AppEngine in the web console, you should be able to find it there.